# Django JSON string to json object

Tags: python, django, mongodb, json

I am using mongodb with django and want to store json object in mongodb. Here is my code

**Model**

```
class Data(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payload = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

**View save data**

```
deviceId = request.POST.get('deviceId')
payload = request.POST.get('payload')
data = Data.objects.create(deviceId=deviceId, payload=payload);
data.save()
```

**View fetch data**

```
data = json.dumps(list(Data.objects.all().values('deviceId','payload')))
```

**Response**

```
{
  "data":{
   "payloads":"{name:\"xyz\"}"
  "id":"xxxxx"
  },
}
```

The problem is with `"payloads":"{name:\"xyz\"}"`. Here is a string instead of json Object.

I want `"payloads":"{name:"xyz"}"`. How can convert this into json object in django. Is there anyway to convert all of the dataset into json object instead of iterating each object from dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to just remove the json.dumps part of the script. That's a python command to translate a valid JSON object into a string!

```
data = list(Data.objects.all().values('deviceId','payload'))
```

Comment: No, Actually it returns a list and I want response in json

Answer (score 0):

To store JSON I recommended to use JSONField.

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
class Data(models.Model):
    deviceId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payload = models.JSONField(max_length=2000)
```